# Decimal multiplication in php

Tags: php, bcmath

I am having a problem with the multiplication of two decimals **`30.63`** and **`0.15`**. My calculator says that it should result in **`4.60`**.

```
$commission = bcmul(30.63, 0.15,2);
```

Result from this is **`4.59`**.

From what I had read bcmul was meant to work with decimal numbers?

Many thanks,

Comment: Throw your calculator in the trashbin. `30.63 x 0.15 = 4.5945` which is closer to 4.59

Comment: 4.59 is perfect answer .

Comment: you are right - calculator is in the bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php) for the `$scale` parameter to `bcmul`:

> This optional parameter is used to set the number of digits after the decimal place in the result.

This essentially means that the number will be rounded **down** (or up for a negative number) when it's used, e.g.

```
> echo bcmul(0.99, 1, 1);
0.9
```

For your values, 30.63 * 0.15 is equal to 4.5945. Supplying a `$scale` value of 2 means that you get 4.59, as you've reported.

I'm not sure why you're expecting 4.60, unless you're specifically expecting the result to be rounded **up**.